# Applying css to divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop set of div elements as in the following image expanding the full web page.But I don't have any idea how to do it.The div elements may have any heights and widths but the appreance should be as follows

[image: Expected view of the divs]

please help me to do this

Comment: Readup on [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) Also, in future add what you have tried

Comment: Do you need fallback to ie11?

Comment: Use case for CSS Grid, see answers. Next time please include the code you have tried. Lazy questions usually breed lazy answers and you've been pretty fortunate this time to actually get answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using css grid. You divide the page in columns and rows

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .main-grid {
        display: grid;
        width: 500px;
        height: 370px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 10px;
    }

    .main-grid :nth-child(1) {
        background: orange;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: -1;
    }

    .main-grid :nth-child(2) {
        background: blue;
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: -1;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 2;
    }

    .main-grid :nth-child(3) {
        background: green;
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: -1;
    }

    .main-grid :nth-child(4) {
        background: yellow;
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: -1;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: -1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a task for CSS grid - a very good tool for building responsive layouts. You can read more about it here: [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right-up"></div>
    <div class= "right-down-a"></div>
    <div class= "right-down-b"> </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  grid-template-columns: 33vw 33vw 33vw;
  grid-template-rows: 50vh 50vh;
  grid-template-areas:
  "left right-up right-up"
  "left right-down-a right-down-b";
  grid-gap: 5px;

}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.right-up {
  grid-area: right-up;
  background-color: green;
}
.right-down-a{
  grid-area: right-down-a;
  background-color: red;
}
.right-down-b{
  grid-area: right-down-b;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

JSfiddle: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/asm1fvbz/5/)